# Is this Arduino hardware question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I just recently started reviewing First Posts and Triage, and I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646503/arduino-button-led-not-working). The `Arduino` tag is not one of the tags that I follow, but I read the question carefully, and the OP is asking about jiggling the components on the board.

I flagged it as "Blatantly off-topic" since it wasn't about programming at all. The flag was disputed -- which is fine, I'm not sweating a disputed flag. It seems that the answer for this question is also primarily addressing circuitry issues, and only dealing with actual programming in a sort of back-handed fashion.

So, did I miss the boat on this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd argue that coding on an Arduino board does require *some* knowledge of the circuity powering it.

That said, the answer seems appropriate and the question seems like it's on topic for here.  I get that it's not a *pure* programming question, but there's enough overlap here with this question and the subject matter that I'm comfortable with giving the OP the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Okay, I'll remember to widen the scope a bit for this tag.